# Eclipse Java application dynamically importing JARs from another application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi, classpath

I have 2 java applications that I need to be able to talk to each other - *if* the second one is installed.  Both applications/frameworks are extensive and the core code is not under my control, but I can extend the parts I need to use, I just can't rewrite what is already there.

My first application is a set of Eclipse based plugins.  It is from here that I need to connect to the second application to extract data from it.

My second application is a client-server based application, and I need to be able to create a headless connection to the server (in place of a client) if the client application is installed on the same machine.  There are Java APIs suitable for doing this, which I have in my Dev environment, but they may or may not be deployed on a user's machine.

I can't bundle the JARs from the second application and deliver them with the first, as this would absolutely be a copyright infringement etc.  So I need to be able to allow the user of the first application to specify the installation directory for the 2nd application (if they have it installed).

What I am hoping to be able to do is get the user of the first application to specify the install directory of the second application, and load whatever classes I need from that location, without having to do much micro configuration.

EDIT: What I have done so far is created 2 OSGI plugins.  The first enables the User of the first application to specify the working directory of the second application.  If this path is set then I am trying to use reflection to load the second plugin, which has references to the classes required for the second application.  BUT on trying to Reflect this class - I cannot seem to find it in the classpath etc.  What I have tried is

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.package.impl.Activator");
```

and

```
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();                   
Class<?> c = classloader.loadClass("com.package.impl.Activator")
```

I have also tried looking at the other classes in the Classpath to try and help, by using

```
ImmutableSet<ClassPath.ClassInfo> paths = ClassPath.from(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()).getAllClasses();
```

but this didn't return any of the expected plugin classes, and contained only framework classes, such as

```
com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher
com.sun.crypto.provider.TlsRsaPremasterSecretGenerator
com.sun.crypto.provider.ai
com.sun.java.accessibility.AccessBridge
com.sun.java.accessibility._AccessibleState
com.sun.java.accessibility.util.AWTEventMonitor
com.sun.java.accessibility.util.java.awt.ButtonTranslator
com.sun.java.accessibility.util.java.awt.TextComponentTranslator
etc...
```

I am not sure what I am missing in regards to setting the classpath, to find my plugin class using reflection. Any Ideas?

PS Both application run on Windows desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that dynamically loading classes the way you are trying, is a dead end. I see two options:

If the **client APIs** are delivered in a **bundle jar** (meaning: it can be loaded as bundle into your OSGi framework), the solution would be to load the client API bundle from your first plugin using the standard OSGi APIs of `BundleContext` and `Bundle` (`BundleContext.installBundle` and `Bundle.start`). This should be possible, since you know the location of the client API jar after the user inputs the installation location. After that, you can do the same for your second bundle that depends on those client APIs. This should bring up all software for performing the functionality.

If the client APIs are delivered in a normal jar *and* you cannot convince the supplier to create a bundle jar for you, the situation is a little more complex. The preferred solution would be to dynamically wrap the client API jar into a bundle jar. There is already software around that performs this action (bnd, pax, eclipse, various frameworks). After the wrapping you are back at the first solution. But question is whether this would be allowed given the licensing terms.

If all of the above fails, I guess there is no other solution then creating software outside your plugin environment that bridges the gap via some kind of RPC solution: You need to write some non-plugin code that uses the client jar. This part runs in its own JVM and communicates with a plugin in your OSGi framework via remote method calls.

Hope this helps or that this answer will cause some follow-ups with a better solution.

Comment: I can add to this that if the Client API bundles are provided via P2, you can install the bundles *with all their dependencies* from the P2 repo with more or less a single P2 API call. Otherwise it may be quite complex (and fragile) to install via BundleContext API.

Comment: Arie, thanks for that. the client APIs are certainly not bundled.  I have tried to find out if the provider can do this, but no luck so far. Second option, I have explored using eclipse, and theoretically worked, but had many issues, if I package all 300 of the JARs, the performance is woeful (server connection time jumps from 8 seconds to 2.5 minutes while it unpacks the JAR). If I try to only package what I need, I continually run missing dependencies that are hard to track down. The creation of a separate program may be the answer.

Comment: @IlyaShinkarenko while some of the APIs are generic, a large proportion are specifically written by the provider, for this application only.

Comment: You may create a P2 repository with all needed dependencies and use P2 API to download and install it with all dependencies at once.

Comment: @IlyaShinkarenko - I can't create a P2 repo, these are not my JARs.  The APIs will either be installed by the 3rd party already for me to use, OR they won't be there and my function won't be operable.  I can't deliver the 3rd party APIs to make my function work.